# How can I validate field by another field value? Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Here's my request rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        "namespace" => "required|max:20",
        "key" => "required|max:30",
        "value" => "required",
        "value_type" => "requied|in:string,integer",
    ];
}
```

I need only integer in the "value" field if "value_type" is "integer". Is there any way to validate it? Laravel 5.4

**I found simple solution**

> ```
> public function rules()
> {
>     $cond = '';
>     if ($this->request->get('value_type') == 'integer') {
>         $cond = '|integer';
>     }
>
>     return [
>         "mf_id" => "required|integer",
>         "resource" => "required|string",
>         "res_id" => "required|integer",
>         "value" => "required{$cond}",
>         "value_type" => "required|in:string,integer",
>         "parent" => "string",
>         "parent_id" => "integer",
>     ];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`$v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules());`

then you need to use Conditionally Adding Rules.

`$v->sometimes(['value'], 'required|integer', function ($data) {
    return is_numeric($input->value_type);
});`

check :-

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules